# Chrome Extension: how can I force a script to start ONLY AFTER the terminus of the previous

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that makes changes in the colors of the images in the web pages.
When the extension is activated (through a icon on the toolbar), the images in all the open tabs are changed.
When the URL of a tab is updated, the images are then changed.
But, in order to hide the original page until the complete change in images, I hide the document (through the "esconde.js"). Afterwards, I call the "recolor.js", which makes the color changing in images. Finally, the "mostra.js" gets the document visible.
The problem is that the document becomes visible before the images are recolored.
So, how can I force that the script "mostra.js" run ONLY AFTER the terminus of the "recolor.js" script ?

Here is part of the file where the scripts are called.

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, info, tab) {
 if (flag){
   if (info.status != "complete") 
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file:"esconde.js", runAt: 'document_start' });
   if (info.status == "complete") {
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file:"recolor.js", runAt: 'document_start' });
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file:"mostra.js", runAt: 'document_end' });
     chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png", tabId:tab.id});
   }
 }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are not using the best solution to do this. Take a look at [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)
before using script injection. If you want a more precise solution, please show us more of your code. For example recolor.js

### **Solution with script injection**

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "YourSampleApp",
  "description": "Inject JS into curent webpage",
  "version": "1.3",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
     "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
     "tabs","http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, info, tab) {
    console.log(tabid, info, tab);
    if (info.status == "complete") {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file:"recolor.js"});
    }
});

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action == "activeScript2"){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(sender.tab.id, {file:"mostra.js"});
    }
});
```

**recolor.js**

```
console.log("Start script 1");
//Do Stuff

setTimeout(function(){
    // When you need use a passing message to active the script 2
    console.log("End script 1");
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({action: "activeScript2"});
},3000);
```

**mostra.js**

```
console.log("script 2")
//Do Stuff !
```

The main idea is to use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to execute the second content script when you need it. Since you must inject scripts from the backgroud, you have to trigger it through message passing.